# Validate attribute's length if present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

How to make validation where presence of model's attribute isn't necessary, but if it is present, attribute's length must be more than three characters?

Comment: What is your Rails version?

Comment: 4.2.0, why do you ask?

Comment: example  with `unless:` has a different syntax in Rails version < 4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can allow attribute to be blank with `allow_blank: true` or `nil` with `allow_nil: true` and also check the `length:` :

```
validates :attr, length: { minimum: 4 }, allow_blank: true
validates :attr, length: { minimum: 4 }, allow_nil: true
```

You can also use `if:` or `unless:` :

```
validates :attr, length: {minimum: 4}, unless: -> (item) { item.blank? }
```